# How to give Ownership to Pi from root to Mount_Folder

Tags: pi-4, python-3, root, user

Here is my workflow and the issues I want to fix.

First I mount the windows shared folder on Raspberry Pi. But in order to use that, I have to mount using sudo.

```
sudo mount.cifs //<hostname or IP address>/share /home/pi/windowshare -o user=<name>
```

Once I run `ls -l`, the folder is in root access.

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root        0 Oct 19  2022  windowshare
```

This is my (test.py) python program.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("/home/pi/Pictures/Test.jpeg")
path = '/home/pi/windowshare'
name = '/test_img.jpg'
cv2.imwrite(f'{path}{name}',img)
```

I just want to save the image to the mount folder. But once I run my python program, it raises the error.

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp (771) imwrite_ imwrite_('/home/pi/windowshare/test_img.jpg'): can't open file for writing: permission denied
```

But it works if I run `sudo python3 test.py`.

So I have used `sudo chmod -R 755 /home/pi/windowshare` but it doesn't work.

I want to run the program `without using sudo`. Could anyone pls help me suggest to solve this issue?

Comment: sudo chown pi pi

Answer (score 2):

Currently I am able to solve it putting uid=1000, gid=1000 in /etc/fstab automount.

In other words, I am using user account which is Pi in my case, not the root by defining UID = 1000 and GID = 1000.

Comment: That's a correct answer; to be a *good* answer, you should explain **why** it works...     P.S. You may select your answer as the *"accepted answer"*; this will let readers know that this answer worked in your case.

Comment: Yes I have put the explanation.